# SpringData and mongoDb timeout

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, spring-data, spring-webflux

I made a request, when I execute it directly in Mongo it gives a result quickly, when I execute the code with SpringData it gives me AsyncRequestTimeoutException (even after the use of the indexes the problem persist).

The Query :

```
@Query("{ $or: [{\"product.adr.structures\": { $elemMatch : {\"_id\":?0 , \"depth\" : ?1 }}} , {\"product.ecat.structures\": { $elemMatch : {\"_id\":?0 , \"depth\" : ?1 }}}]}")
Flux<ProductHawk>  findByStructureLevel(String structureLevelId , Integer structureLevelType);
```

what i can do? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **spring.mvc.async.request-timeout** property to -1. In this way you'll disable timeout constraint in your application.

Comment: no, it works well when there is not much data to extract.

Comment: @user2639974, try to set spring.mvc.async.request-timeout to -1. In this way you'll disable timeout constraint in your application.

Comment: I have already tried this solution but my query takes a lot of time which is annoying, and I do not know if the query from springData uses indexes created or not.